# Printing PHP float with 2 digits after the decimal point?

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal

Is there an easy way to `echo` a float number with a specific amount of digits after the decimal point?

For example: `$sum = 3.1234566768;` I would like to echo $sum and get: `3.12`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

use number_format()

```
number_format($sum,2);
```

Comment: Consider that `number_format()` also rounds the value. `$sum = 3.1264566768;` will give `3.13`.

Comment: Note that this will output a string instead of a float. Not that the OP cares about it, but it's good to mention.

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
$sum = 3.1234566768;
$rounded = round($sum, 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo number_format($sum, 2); // 3.12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo number_format((float)$ans, 4, '.', '');
```

I think this will work out